# Jupyter Notebook error. No such file or directory C:.../HOME

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have installed Anaconda2, and today decided to update to Anaconda3. I installed Anaconda3 at the same time as I uninstalled Anaconda2.

Now, Jupyter Notebook shows this error and quits every time I try to start it.

The path in the error message is: "C:\Users\Hongyi\Documents\%HOME%"

What is causing Jupyter Notebook to quit?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to re install the Anaconda 3 again after the error?

Comment: @DeepakM Not yet, because I have read on github where people posed the same problem after reinstalling it three times. But I guess I'll try it if no other solution comes up.

Comment: You've got that weird looking `Y` character in there... probably messing it up

Comment: Ok what I recommend is un -install both environments. Thought the program un installed Some components of Anaconda still exist. Go to your local folder where the Anaconda components were stored or search your local disk for anything associated with Anaconda  and delete everything consisting with Anaconda(Note: You may need to re install all your packages again). Then try running the installer again.

Comment: Also out of curiosity how did you un install the Anaconda 2?

Comment: @DeepakM I used the "uninstall" application in the Anaconda2 folder. I will try your method.

Comment: @cricket_007 I will look into that. Thanks. Thought it may be due to the system language is not set to English.

Comment: Maybe, or that terminal doesn't like the chosen font style.

Comment: @cricket_007 I changed the system language, and how it is showing "C:\Users\Hongyi\Documents\%HOME%"

Comment: `%HOME%` should be a Windows environment variable that is resolved by your system...

Comment: It looks like some config has been messed up (maybe written in some unexpected encoding). You can try to set the environmental variables `JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR` etc. directly in the shell session. Read the docs for an explanation. https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay it looks like I found a solution.

Jupyter started running after I created the appropriate folder in the appropriate path.

In my case, it is creating a folder named %HOME% (with percent signs), in the path shown in the error message.

Now Jupyter is up and running.

Thank you guys for your thoughts and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

After readed this solution I tried another one (a comfortable one for me): 
Open the location of the "Jupyter Notebook" shortcut (right click > More > File location) and right click again > Properties. In the Destination field (Sorry if the label is another ... the thing is that my Windows is in Spanish and I don't remember how it's labeled this field in English) just change the %HOME% at the end for a path to your "Work Folder" (if you have not created one then just create it). And this way It works also.